# NesteJS with TypeORM - hooks and listeners not working

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

#### Solution

With the solution posted below my `create` function `player.service.ts` now looks like this:

```js
async create(createPlayerDto: CreatePlayerDto): Promise<Player> {
  const newPlayer = this.playerRepository.create(createPlayerDto);
  return await this.playerRepository.save(newPlayer);
}
```

The hook within my player.entity.ts:

```js
@BeforeInsert()
async hashPassword() {
  console.log('Hash password!');
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, this.saltOrRounds);
}
```

---

#### Problem

For my project with NestJS I have created a Player entity (`player.entity.ts`), which has the following columns and one hook. I have connected a MySQL8.0 database via the TypeORM package.

```js
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  BeforeInsert,
} from 'typeorm';

import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Entity({ name: 'players' })
export class Player {
  readonly saltOrRounds = 10;

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    unique: true,
  })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  email: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    name: 'created_at',
    type: 'datetime',
  })
  created_at: 'datetime';

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: 'updated_at',
    type: 'datetime',
  })
  updated_at: 'datetime';

  @BeforeInsert()
  async hashPassword() {
    return (
      this.password && (await bcrypt.hash(this.password, this.saltOrRounds))
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the `@BeforeInsert()` hook should take the password, hash it and then return the hashed password.

The relevant route for the creation of a new player is placed within the `players.controller.ts`:

```js
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PlayersService } from './players.service';
import { CreatePlayerDto } from './dto/create-player.dto';
import { Player } from './interfaces/player.interface';

@Controller('players')
export class PlayersController {
  constructor(private playerService: PlayersService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createPlayerDto: CreatePlayerDto) {
    return this.playerService.create(createPlayerDto);
  }
}
```

The controller utilizes the `player.service.ts` and makes uses the EntityManager to perform the create/insert operation:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectEntityManager, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Player } from './entities/player.entity';
import { EntityManager, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CreatePlayerDto } from './dto/create-player.dto';

@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectEntityManager()
    private entityManager: EntityManager,
    @InjectRepository(Player)
    private playerRepository: Repository<Player>,
  ) {}

  async create(createPlayerDto: CreatePlayerDto): Promise<Player> {
    return this.entityManager.save(Player, createPlayerDto);
  }
}
```

I've also tried to use the Repository with the same result. A new player is created everytime I make a POST request to the `/create` endpoint. But unfortunatelly none of the used hooks and/or listeners work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate the Entity, assign the attributes to it and then save.

```js
async create(attributes: DeepPartial<T>) {
    const playerEntity = Object.assign(new Player(), attributes);
    return this.repository.save(playerEntity);
}
```

or you could use the `create` method on the repository and then save it.

```js
const record = playerRepository.create(attributes);
await playerRepository.save(record);
```